# Use of holier-than-thou phrase

Tags: phrases, pronunciation

Can I use the phrase (new to me) `holier-than-thou` like

```
don't give holier-than-thou attitude.
```

And what is more possibilities of using this phrase? What is the correct pronunciation of the phrase?

**P.S:** English is not my first language.

Comment: You could look up all possibilities of usage at [Wordnik](http://www.wordnik.com/words/holier-than-thou).

The pronunciation is available in any dictionary.

Comment: The pronunciation is that of the three words "holier" (i.e. "more holy"), "than", "thou", which you can look up in a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your sentence is missing an object and a demonstrative adjective.  *Who* is the target of the holier-than-thou attitude?  *Which/how much* attitude are you referring to?

You would need to add a couple of words such as:

> Don't give **me that** holier than thou attitude.

or

> Don't give **your friend so much** holier than thou attitude.

Comment: How to pronounce it? please

Comment: The [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/holier-than-thou) provides vocal pronuncations; just click on the bright red speaker icon.  Or, try [Forvo](http://www.forvo.com/word/holier-than-thou/#en)

Comment: @Joel, are you sure "that" is required here?

Comment: @Pacerier technically, perhaps not, but I don't think that usage would be common. In practice, you need something else there to modify the phrase "holier than thou". You could say "Don't give me *your*..." instead of "Don't give me *that*..." but I don't think you would hear a native English speaker say simply "Don't give me holier than thou attitude."   I can't point to a rule that says it would be wrong, but I can't think of a case when I've heard the expression used that way.